# How to prove that $\ell_{\infty}$ has no Schauder basis by contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about:[schauder basis for $\ell_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392555/schauder-basis-for-ell-infty)

> I know that $\ell_\infty$ is not separable, therefore has no Schauder basis.
> However I cannot understand why the set $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, \dotsc \}$ where $e_1=(1,0,0,\dotsc), e_2=(0,1,0,0,\dotsc), \dotsc$ can not work as a Schauder basis.

One  answer is that let $x=(1,1,1,\ldots)\in \ell_\infty$. The proof of that "$\ell_{\infty}$ has no Schauder basis by contradiction?

**Question:**

(1) The standard basis $\{e_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is not Schauder basis

(2) What can we get from the results "$\sum_{I=1}^{\infty}x_ie_i$ does not converges to $x$"? I just read the proof in the second answer in [schauder basis for $\ell_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392555/schauder-basis-for-ell-infty). I am confused about the answer.

> Let $x=(1,1,1,\ldots)\in \ell_\infty$ if $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}x_ie_i,$ then for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$\left\|x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_ne_n\right\|_{\infty}=\|(0,\ldots,0,1,1,1,\ldots)\|_{\infty}=1\not\to0,$$ so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}x_ie_i$ does not converge to $x.$

---

The proof of (1): Does it make sense?

Suppse that $\{e_n\}$ is a Schauder basis. Then for every $x\in \ell_{\infty}$ we have $x=\sum_{I=1}^{\infty} x_ie_i$. That means as $n \to\infty$,
$$
0\le \sup_{k\ge n+1}|x_k|=\|(0,0,\dots,0, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\dots)\|_{\infty}=\|x-\sum_{I=1}^n x_ie_i\|_{\infty}\to 0
$$

Thus, $x_k=0$ for $k\ge n+1$. So
$$
x=\sum_{I=1}^n x_ie_i
$$

But this is impossible. Does it a contradiction?

Comment: (1) doesn't prove there is no Schauder basis.  You are committing the cardinal sin of using the same symbol $e_n$ for two different things (a) some (assumed exist) Schauder basis and (b) the "standard" basis in $\ell_p\hookrightarrow\ell_\infty$,

Comment: @user10354138 So how to prove (1)?

Comment: @user10354138 Well, I know that since $\ell_{\infty}$ is not separable, then it does not have Schauder basis.

Comment: You somehow have inserted the assumption that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to zero. But that is not necessary for $x\in\ell_\infty$, such sequences only need to be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your proof isn't valid. You can't draw the conclusion that $\ x_k=0\ $ for all $\ k\ $ exceeding some integer $\ n\ $ from the mere fact that $\ \sup_\limits{k\ge n+1}\big|x_k\big|\rightarrow$$\,0\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.   The latter condition will hold if $\ x_k=\frac{1}{k}\ $, for instance, but then $\ x_k\ne0\ $ for *any* $\ k\ $.

Nor can you obtain a contradiction by choosing some *arbitrary* $\ x\in\ell_\infty\ $ and assuming that $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^nx_ke_k=x\ $, because there happen to be members $\ x\ $ of $\ \ell_\infty\ $ for which this latter  condition *does* hold (namely, those $\ x\ $ for which $\ \lim_\limits{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=0\ $), and an arbitrarily chosen $\ x\ $ could well be one of them unless you've specified otherwise.

For $\ \big\{e_n\big\}_{n\ge1}\ $ to be a Schauder basis, however, it must be true that *for every* $\ x\in\ell_\infty\ $ there exists a *unique* sequence $\ \big\{y_k\big\}_{k=1}^\infty\ $ such that  $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^ny_ke_k=$$\ x\ $. Therefore, to show that it's *not* a Schauder basis you only need to find a *single* member of $\ \ell_\infty\ $ for which $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^ny_ke_k\ne x\ $ for *any* sequence $\ \big\{y_k\big\}_{k=1}^\infty\ $, and $\ x=(1,1,1,\dots)\ $ happens to be one such.

There's one relatively minor blemish in the proof you cite from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392555/schauder-basis-for-ell-infty/1393045#1393045), which you also repeat in your attempted proof— namely, the assumption that *if* $\ x=\big(x_1,x_2,\dots\big)\in\ell_\infty\ $ and $\ x=\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty y_ne_n\ $ then $\ y_i=x_i\ $ must necessarily hold for all $\ i\ $.  Since I'm pretty sure I can see how to prove this hypothetical statement, and also that the proof won't be difficult, I might  be prepared to let you get away with "It's easy to see that" it's true. However, I *wouldn't* be prepared to let you get away with "It's obvious" that it's true, especially because I *know* that in the case when $\ x=$$\,(1,1,\dots)\ $ no such sequence $\ \big\{y_k\big\}_{k=1}^\infty\ $ can exist.

Here's how you can modify your attempted proof so that it does work:

Suppose that $\ \big\{e_n\big\} $ is a Schauder basis. Then since $\ x=$$\,(1,1,\dots)\in$$\,\ell_\infty\ $ we have $\ x=$$\,\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty y_ne_n\ $ for some sequence $\ \big\{y_k\big\}_{k=1}^\infty\ $ of complex numbers.  This means that as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $,
\begin{align}
\left\|x-\sum_\limits{i=1}^n y_ie_i\right\|_\infty&=\big\|\big(1-y_1,1-y_2,\dots,1-y_n,1,1,\dots\big)\big\|_\infty\\
&\rightarrow0\ .
\end{align}
But
\begin{align}
\big\|\big(1-y_1,1-y_2,\dots,1-y_n,1,1,\dots\big)\big\|_\infty
&=\sup\big(|1-y_1|,|1-y_2|,\dots,|1-y_n|,1,1,\dots\big)\\
&\ge1
\end{align}
for all $\ n\ $, and it's impossible for a sequence that's never less than $\ 1\ $ to converge to $\ 0\ $.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a question about the first argument that is wrong for $\sup_{k\ge n+1}|x_k|\to 0$. In this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782774/the-proof-of-c-00-is-not-complete, I used the similar thing $|x_{ni}-x_i|\le \|x_n-x\|_{\infty}\to \infty$. Why in that question we have $x_{ni}=x_i$, then $x=(1, 1/2, 1/3,\dots)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  In the question you cite you've hypothesized that $\ x_n\rightarrow x\ $ in $\ c_{00}\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ which means that $\ \|x_n-x\|\rightarrow0\ $ (not $\ \|x_n-x\|\rightarrow\infty\ $), and for $\ n\ge i\ $ you have $\ x_{ni}=\frac{1}{i}\ $, so $\ \big|x_{ni}-x_i\big|$$\,=\left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|\le$$\,\big\|x_n-x\big\|_\infty\ $ for $\ n\ge i\ $ and if $\ \big\|x_n-x\big\|_\infty\rightarrow0\ $ then that implies $\ \left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|=0\ $.

Comment: The difference between that case and your argument here is that here you *don't* have $$\ \big|x_i\big|\le \big\|0,0,\dots,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots\big\|_\infty\ $$ for $\ n>i\ $.

Comment: But this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235687/schauder-basis-for-c-0 used the same method as mine. Why my method does not work?

Comment: Sorry, why $|1/i -x_i|\le \|x_n-x\|_\infty$ holds for $n\ge i$ but not for all $n$?

Comment: So in our case, $|x_i|\le \|(0,\dots, 0, x_{n+1},\dots\|_\infty\to 0$ for $i>n+1$, right? So $x_{n+1}=x_{n+2}=\dots=0$. Does it make sense? So in my answer, I wrote $x=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$.

Comment: No, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235687/schauder-basis-for-c-0/1334154#1334154) is *not* using "the same method" you've tried to use here.  The deduction of the argument in that answer is that $\ \sup_\limits{k\ge n+1}\big|a_k\big|\color{red}{<\epsilon}\ $ for $\ n\ge n_0\ $ (and hence  $\ \big|a_k\big|\color{red}{<\epsilon}\ $ for $\ k>n_0\ $), *not* that $\ a_k\color{red}{=0}\ $ for $\ k>n_0\ $.

Comment: Under the conditions specified in  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782774/the-proof-of-c-00-is-not-complete) it follows from the conditions specified that $\ x_i=\frac{1}{i}\ $ must hold for all $\ i\ $ and hence $\ \left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|\le\big\|x_n-x\|_\infty\ $ does indeed hold for all $\ n\ $.  The identity $\ x_i=\frac{1}{i}\ $ is not one of the conditions originally specified, however, but merely a consequence of them, so it can't be *assumed* until it's been proved.

Comment: At the point in the argument in my first comment where I deduce the inequality  $\ \left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|\le\big\|x_n-x\|_\infty\ $ from the equation $\ \big|x_{ni}-x_i\big|=$$\,\left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|\ $ and the inequality $\ \big|x_{ni}-x_i\big|\le\big\|x_n-x\|_\infty\ $ the given identity *has not yet been proved* and the equation does not hold for $\ n<i\ .$ At that stage I can therefore assert only that $\ \left|\frac{1}{i}-x_i\right|\le\big\|x_n-x\|_\infty\ $ holds for $\ n\ge i\ $, not that it holds for all $\ n\ $.